# How do I specify that I want something to be present in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lookup, pattern-guards

I have a guard and the condition is that lookup x list == something i.e. x is in the list. I tried:

```
| lookup x list == _ = my code here
```

But when loading the function I get a "pattern syntax in expression context" error?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a guard like

```
| any ((x ==) . fst) list = ... code ...
```

The specific error message you get is because `_` is not a valid identifier. The token `_` is only valid in pattern matches, and pattern matches can only be used in places that explicitly allow them. Patterns are never an expression, so they can't be used any place that expects an arbitrary expression.

If you enable the `PatternGuards` extension in GHC, you could also do what you want with syntax like:

```
| Just _ <- lookup x list = ... code ...
```

Note that I'm matching on `Just` results, rather than all results. Remember that `lookup` still produces *a* value when it doesn't find something, and that the `_` pattern matches all values.

Noting that pattern guard syntax works out to be the same amount of typing here, the advantage to using it in this case is that it also lets you bind a name to the value looked up, if you so desire.

```
| Just y <- lookup x list = ... code that uses y...
```

Doing this without pattern guards would require a pattern match inside the body, which would possibly be a bit unsatisfying.

Comment: It is not illegal to have pattern matching in a guard (just stick a `case…of` in there.) However, the comparison operator `(==)` expects two bools, not a bool and a pattern.

Comment: @kqr Hmm, I worded that slightly badly.  Fixing.

Comment: Whoops, I just realized my answer was wrong anyway.  Fixed now.

Comment: No I don't like . notation what is:

    | any ((x ==) . fst) list = ... code ...

without the . ?

Comment: @James `(x ==) . fst` is the same thing as `\t -> x == fst t`.

Comment: @James The `.` operator in Haskell is something you should learn about. There's a reason it's a single character infix operator - it is powerful and useful. It allows you to compose two functions together into a new function with minimal syntactic overhead - an important building block for languages that are about combining small single-purpose functions into the logic you need.

Comment: Okay but just for reference how would you write the function the same way without a . ?

Comment: @Carl Can you recommend any good guides on the . (how do I make it look like code in comments?) operator?

Comment: @James I can only tell you how I learned about it..  I spent a bunch of time in the #haskell irc channel on freenode, asking beginner questions, and paying attention to answers to other questions. Sooner or later, I just absorbed it. I don't know if there's any way to get used to it other than practice.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you find you want to leave the gratuitous pattern-matching hidden in a library...

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

...
    | isJust (lookup x list) = ...
```